# SEO friendly URLs with category/subcategories/article slug? [Laravel]

Tags: laravel, seo, laravel-5, friendly-url, nested-sets

First of all, I have *Article* model and *articles* table in the database. Each article can be shown using Laravel's standard URI structure: `www.example.com/articles/5`   (where `5` the article `id`.). Each article has a **slug** field (**slug** column in the *articles* table) , so with *Route Model Binding* it is easy to change this and have a slug instead of id in the URI:

In **RouteServiceProvider.php** I just added:

```
 public function boot(Router $router)
 {
    parent::boot($router);

    \Route::bind('articles', function($slug) {
        return \App\Article::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

... and now I can open articles with: `www.example.com/articles/this-is-some-slug` .

On the other hand, each article belongs to one category.  For example, let's say that there are the following categories:

- Politics
- Sport

  - Football
  - Tennis

    - ATP
    - WTA
- Culture

I created these categories by using **Baum** (an implementation of the **Nested Set** pattern for Laravel 5's Eloquent ORM). So there is a `Category` model and `categories` table in the database:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');

        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('lft')->nullable();
        $table->integer('rgt')->nullable();
        $table->integer('depth')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
```

Of course, in `articles` table there is a column `category_id` because of *One-to-Many* relationship (one Article belongs to one Category,  one Category can have many Articles).

All articles belonging to some category can be displayed via the following URL: `www.example.com/articles/category/1` (where `1` is the `id`). If we add `slug` column to the *categories* table & set *Route Model Binding* :

```
    \Route::bind('category', function($slug) {
        return \App\Category::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    });
```

then we will use a slug instead of id: `www.example.com/articles/category/politics` (this will display all the articles belonging to the category *politics*).

But I would like to have URIs with the following structure:

- `www.example.com/sport/tennis/wta/article_slug` (/category/subcategory/subcategory/article_slug)
- `www.example.com/politics/article_slug` (/category/article_slug )

and so on...

The problem is that I have no idea how to do this with Laravel. Is it even possible? How would you solve this problem?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

SEO friendly URLs with category/subcategories/article slug?

Answer (score 3):

To produce a url that's `example.com/category/subcategory/article` is pretty simple, but you're obviously looking to add the complexity of multiple subcategories. For that we'll need to look at [route parameter regex constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Using regex in your route parameter constraints you can get the subcategories as a string eg. `subcategory1/subcategory2` and then pass it via another custom binding or directly to your controller.

Here's an example of the route you need with the route parameter constraint added:

```
// Route to closure
Route::get('/{category}/{subcategories}/{article}', function($category, $subcategories, $article) 
{
    return $subcategories;
})->where('subcategories', '(.*)');

// Route to controller method
Route::get('/{category}/{subcategories}/{article}', 'ArticlesController@show')->where('subcategories', '(.*)');
```

And an example of a custom binding for your subcategories parameter that returns the subcategories as an array:

```
$router->bind('subcategories', function ($value) {
    return explode('/', $value);
});
```

**Caveat:** The only problem you will run into using the route parameter bindings in the way you've described, is that the article loaded here is only dependant on the slug being correct. It will still load if the categories in the url are unrelated, which you'll need to take care of in your controller logic.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do so as you explained here, and let you know if it worked. What is your opinion about storing the full path in a field, could it be a better solution in case of deeply nested categories? What are the disadvantages compared to the solution that you presented here... I mean, what's your opinion. Thanks again and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking sorry. Do you mean store the full path in a variable to pass to the controller? Or stored in the database?