# Laravel 10 route create beautiful URL

Tags: laravel, routes

I have route:

```
Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

Within URL (1): `domain.com/posts` will show all posts.
Within URL (2): `domain.com/posts?status=trashed` will show all soft deleted posts.
How I want to create a beautiful URL which replace the URL (2)?
Such as `domain.com/posts/status/trashed`, or `domain.com/posts-trashed` ...
How I write the route?

I want to create a beautiful URL which replace the URL `domain.com/posts?status=trashed`

Comment: You could juste define your routes without using resources :  `Route::get('posts/{trashed?}', PostController@index')` and `public function index(Request $request, $trashed = false)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SEO friendly URLs with category/subcategories/article slug? \[Laravel\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927105/seo-friendly-urls-with-category-subcategories-article-slug-laravel)

Comment: Sorry but it not work for me

Answer (score 0):

To create a more user-friendly URL for showing trashed posts instead of using a query parameter like domain.com/posts?status=trashed, you can define a custom route that handles this scenario. You can do this by adding a route with a specific URI pattern and then updating your controller to handle the request appropriately.

Here's how you can achieve this:

Define a custom route in your routes/web.php file:

```
Route::get('posts/trashed', [PostController::class, 'trashed'])->name('posts.trashed');
```

This route maps the URL domain.com/posts/trashed to a trashed method in your PostController. You can choose any URI segment you like, but in this example, I'm using trashed.

In your PostController, create a trashed method to handle the request:

```
public function trashed()
{
    $trashedPosts = Post::onlyTrashed()->get();

    return view('posts.trashed', compact('trashedPosts'));
}
```

In this example, the trashed method retrieves the soft-deleted posts and returns them to a view. You should customize this method according to your application's requirements.

Create a view file (e.g., resources/views/posts/trashed.blade.php) to display the trashed posts.
Now, you can access the trashed posts by visiting the URL domain.com/posts/trashed. This provides a more user-friendly URL structure compared to using query parameters.

Comment: I want to use `index` method for both route. But any way your route not work

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can create two routes, namely:

```php
Route::get('posts/status/trashed',[PostController::class,'trashed'])->name('posts.trashed');
Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

Comment: I want to use `index` method for both route